# Is there a way to import bilingual wordlists from wiktionary, omegawiki or wordnet online?

Tags: open-source, wiki, dictionary, mediawiki, wiktionary

I would like to import bilingual wordlists from wiktionary, omegawiki or wordnet but without using php, python, mysql beacuse I am not an expert in this tehnologies. I would like to query it online or get them in an excel, notepad or other format.

The Import should go into an excel table, sql server database, access database or I would also be happy to query online and make bilingual dictionaries. I have windows 7.

Comment: Import into what? And what OS must it run on, or should it be a web-app?

Comment: Import into an excel table, sql server database, access database or I would also be happy to query online and make bilingual dictionaries. I have windows 7. What would be an easier solution?

Comment: I don't have any solution for you, sorry – I just wanted to make sure all required details are available, so you get a better chance for good recommendations.

Comment: Wiktionary does not have bilingual lists in machine-readable form ([yet](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wikidata_for_Wiktionary_announcement.pdf)).

Comment: This means that I can`t make dictionaries with Wiktionary like English-German, English-Dutch and other dictionaries? Is Wiktionary a monolingual dictionary?